# Golang cannot find package in Docker image

Tags: docker, go

So, I am trying to dockerize a golang application with different directories containing supplementary code for my main file. 
I am using **gorilla/mux**. The directory structure looks like this.

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com/user/server
  |--- Dockerfile 
  |--- main.go 
  |--- routes/ 
         handlers.go 
  |--- public/ 
         index.gohtml
```

It works on my host machine with no problem. The problem is that when I try to deploy the docker image it does not run and exits shortly after creation. I have tried changing the **WORKDIR** command in my dockerfile to **/go/src** and dump all my files there, but still no luck. I have also tried the official documentation on [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/golang). Doesn't work either.

My Dockerfile.

```
FROM golang:latest  
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/user/server
COPY . .
RUN go get -d github.com/gorilla/mux

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["go","run","main.go"]
```

My golang **main.go**

```golang
package main 

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/user/server/routes"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)
func main(){
  //... 
}
```

I get this error message when I check the logs of my docker image.

**Error Message**

```
main.go:5:2: cannot find package "github.com/user/server/routes" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/user/server/routes (from $GOROOT)
    /go/src/github.com/user/server/routes (from $GOPATH)
```

Comment: Have you tried running a `tree`/`ls -R` in your image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following `Docker` file:

```
# GO Repo base repo
FROM golang:1.12.0-alpine3.9 as builder

RUN apk add git

# Add Maintainer Info
LABEL maintainer="<>"

RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod go.sum ./

# Download all the dependencies
RUN go mod download

COPY . .

# Build the Go app
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o main .

# GO Repo base repo
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates curl

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app/

# Copy the Pre-built binary file from the previous stage
COPY --from=builder /app/main .

# Expose port 8000
EXPOSE 8000

# Run Executable
CMD ["./main"]
```

Here, we are creating an intermediate `docker builder` container, copying the code into it, build the code inside the `builder` container and then copy the `binary` image to the actual docker.

This will help in both having all the dependencies in the final container and also, the size of the final image will be very small

Comment: How is this different from what's in the question, and why will it help?  (Of note, the question doesn't appear to be using Go modules.)

Comment: This will `download` all the dependencies mentioned in `go.mod` thereby not having to install any dependency manually. (I have tried something similar to fix dependencies error. Hope it helps OP too)

Comment: yes, this worked. Thank you !!! 
I wasn't aware of ```go.mod``` and I will look into it more. I just had to write ```go mod init``` and ```go mod tidy``` to create the additional files.

Comment: There is no other option that doesn't require rebuild the image all the time?